# Correct way to deploy deploy a container from GitLab to EC2

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I try to deploy my container from gitlab registry to EC2 Instance, I arrived to deploy my container, but when I change something, and want to deploy again, It is required to remove the old container and the old images and deploy again, for that I create this script to remove every thing and deploy again.

```
...
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master

  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@$DEPLOY_SERVER "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com &&
     docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) &&
     docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) &&
     docker pull registry.gitlab.com/doesntmatter/demo:latest &&
     docker image tag registry.gitlab.com/doesntmatter/demo:latest doesntmatter/demo &&
     docker run -d -p 80:8080 doesntmatter/demo"
```

When I try this script, I got this error:

```
 "docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.    <<-------------------- error
 See 'docker stop --help'.
 Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
 Stop one or more running containers
Running after script
00:01
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

if you look closer, I use `$(docker ps -a -q)` after the the docker stop.

Questions:

1. I know this is not the wonderful way to make my deploys (a developer here), can you please suggest other ways, just with using gitlab and ec2.
2. Is there any way to avoid this error, when I have or not containers in my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably no containers were running when the job was executed.

To avoid this behavior, you can change a bit you command to have :

```
docker ps -a -q | xargs -r sudo docker stop
docker ps -a -q | xargs -r sudo docker rm
```

These will not produce errors if no containers are running.

Afterwards, indeed there are other way to deploy a container on AWS where there are services handling containers very well like [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) or [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). Think also about [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to deploy your infrastructure using IaC principle (even for you ec2 instance).

Comment: Good job, this work very well, thank you for the advises also, I will follow what you mentioned in your answer :)

Comment: back to uv your answer when I got enough reputation

Comment: .as promised ;D